# Changing posts on grid to a fixed size (Photo posts with writing underneath.)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the size of the posts on grid mode in tumblr.

I noticed that I can change the width of each post through CSS. But I just cannot seem to find where I change the height size of a grid post to a fixed size.

For example, I would like to post an image with words underneath it and if the text does not fit in the fixed size. I would like the post to have periods to show that they can continue reading by clicking on the post.

I have been using the Chrome Developer Tools to find certain div and class tags, but I just cannot seem to figure this out.

All help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at using the styles `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: Wow! first of all thank you! That was exactly what I am looking for but now I have run into another issue. I am trying to put in a lot of text but I would like the text-overflow: ellipsis to go into effect after the fifth line of text. This means I would have to change the actual size of the post correct?

Comment: Added my suggestion as an answer.

Comment: You can limit the number of lines visible, but I don't think there is a pure css solution for also getting an ellipsis for multiline elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the styles `overflow` and `text-overflow` to control layout.

```
.truncate {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and then add the class `truncate`to your element.